# How to add new value inside array of object by id (not new item)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying add a new `value` inside my array by id. I'm not trying add a new item in my array... For this I can use `push()`, but it add new item not a new value.

I'm trying do it:

My array:

```
const data = 
[  
   {  
      "id": 1,
      "year":2019,
      "value": 2,
   },
   {  
      "id": 2,
      "year": 2019,
      "value": 89,
   },   
   {  
      "id": 3,
      "year": 2019,
      "value": 99,
   }   
]
```

Inside an especific `id` I would to add a new value like this:

```
data.forEach(item => {
  if(item.id === 2){
    //data inside id 2 -> item: 55
  }
})
```

So my new `data`array looks like this:

```
const data = 
[  
   {  
      "id": 1,
      "year":2019,
      "value": 2,
   },
   {  
      "id": 2,
      "year": 2019,
      "value": 89,
      "item": 55
   },   
   {  
      "id": 3,
      "year": 2019,
      "value": 99,
   }   
]
```

In most of my searches, I found just how to add a new element. But this I know how to do (`push()`). 
So how to add a new value inside specified `id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just assign the property you want to add:

```
data.forEach(item => {
  if(item.id === 2){
    item.item = 55;
  }
})
```

If the IDs are unique, you can use the `.find()` method:

```
var el = data.find(item => item.id === 2);
if (el) {
  el.item = 55;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
data.find(x=> x.id==2).item=55;
```

```js
const data = 
[  
   {  
      "id": 1,
      "year":2019,
      "value": 2,
   },
   {  
      "id": 2,
      "year": 2019,
      "value": 89,
   },   
   {  
      "id": 3,
      "year": 2019,
      "value": 99,
   }   
]

data.find(x=>x.id==2).item=55;

console.log(data);
```

Comment: @Barmar Without knowing the context, we can't be sure if that's good or bad. If it's expected that the ID should always be in that object, perhaps it *should* throw an error in the case it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate and assign value based on your criteria

```
data.map(function(x){
  if(x.id == 2){
    x.value = 100;
  }
})
```

Comment: Don't use `map()` if you're not using the result, use `.forEach()`.

Comment: @Barmar Wouldn't be map good when just changing or altering data. It will be faster and returns new array. Any thoughts

Comment: @Kamal `map` is good when transforming all elements in an array. In your example, you're not mapping *anything* - you are just using `map` as a vehicle to iterate over an array. In such a case, it *works*, but it's just a very misleading "code smell". Not to mention, an iterative like `.find()` (which exits when it finds the element its looking for), will be much more efficient.

Comment: The only difference between `.map()` and `.forEach()` is that `.map()` collects the results of the callback function into a new array. Why choose a function that does X+Y when there's another function that just does X and you don't care about Y?

Comment: Thanks @TylerRoper and Barmar for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement method using `Array.find` to avoid unnecessary iterations:

```js
const array = [  
   {  
      "id": 1,
      "year":2019,
      "value": 2,
   },
   {  
      "id": 2,
      "year": 2019,
      "value": 89,
   },   
   {  
      "id": 3,
      "year": 2019,
      "value": 99,
   }   
];

const changeValue = (array, id, field, value) =>
  array.find(el => el.id === id)[field] = value;

changeValue(array, 1, 'year', 9999);
console.log('result: ', array);
```

Comment: @Barmar It'swill simplify debugg process.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is more or less right there. To set the property of an item, you can do either `object.propertyName = ...` or `object["propertyName"] = ...`.

With that, you'd simply need to update your example to look like this:

```
data.forEach(item => {
  if(item.id === 2){
    item.item = 55; //data inside id 2 -> item: 55
  }
})
```

As a more efficient alternative, consider [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). It won't continue to loop through the array after it finds the `id`, whereas your `forEach` will *always* loop through the array in its entirety.

```js
const data = [ { "id": 1, "year":2019, "value": 2, }, { "id": 2, "year": 2019, "value": 89, }, { "id": 3, "year": 2019, "value": 99, } ];

( data.find(({id})=> id === 2) || {} ).item = 55;
console.log(data);
```

You'll notice I've followed the `.find()` with `|| {}`. This is simply so that if an item with `id === 2` isn't found, attempting to set the property won't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects and you want to add a field to one of the objects. So, first, you have to find the object you want to change. Array items can be accessed by index, but you don't know the index. There are several methods to find an item in an array.

```
var item = data.find(function(d, i){
    return item.id === 2; //criteria
});
```

or in ES6 syntax:

```
var item = data.find(d=>d.id == 2);
```

after that, you can change item the way you want.

```
item.anotherField = 'another value';
```

As you said, `push()` adds an item to the array. It doesn't change existing items in the array.